# One async call per button. How do I handle users clicking multiple buttons in quick succession?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I've an admin page with multiple buttons that make axios calls to change the content. Each button makes a different call.

When the user clicks button 1, data is retrieved from the server to be displayed onscreen. But if the user clicks button 1, then 2 in quick succession, the UI displays data from 1, then 2.

This isn't necessarily a massive problem, but I would like to know the best approach, as it does cause me issues when animating the data with gsap (see below).

Is the best approach to try and using tokens to cancel the axios request?

Codepen: [Non-animation example](https://codepen.io/nwoodward/pen/QWOgBpR?editors=0010)
A slightly different example [with animation](https://codepen.io/nwoodward/pen/BamZNod?editors=0011)

JS

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', async e => {
  const item1 = e.target.closest('.item1');
  const item2 = e.target.closest('.item2');
  const item3 = e.target.closest('.item3');
    
    if(item1) {
      await dummyAsync(); 
      changeContent(1);
    }
    if(item2) {
      await dummyAsync();  
      changeContent(2);
    }
    if(item3) {
      await dummyAsync();
      changeContent(3);
    }
});

function dummyAsync() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(), 2000);
  });
}

function changeContent(item) {
  // Clear previous content
  const wrapper = document.querySelector('.content-wrapper');
  while(wrapper.firstChild) wrapper.removeChild(wrapper.firstChild);
  
  const dummyTable = `<div class="table">This is table number: ${item}</div>`;
  
  // Add table
  wrapper.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', dummyTable);
};
```

HTML & CSS

```
<div class="menu">
  <div class="item item1">Item1</div>
  <div class="item item2">Item2</div>
  <div class="item item3">Item3</div>
</div>
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="content">Content</div>
</div>

.menu { 
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 20rem;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey; 
}
.item {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 1rem;
  z-index: 2;
}

.content-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey; 
  height: 20rem;
}

.table {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 25rem;
  height: 10rem;
  border: 1px dotted grey;
}
```

Comment: `Is the best approach to try and using tokens to cancel the axios request?` that's what I'd do - is it the best? that's an opinion :p

Comment: *a good approach :D Good to know, thanks. Never done it before, hopefully it's fairly self-explanatory, but no doubt axios will complicate it somehow XD

Comment: @Bravo - Would I need to have a flag of some sort, like `isActive`, which I could use as a condition to call `source.cancel()`, if source was `const source = axios.CancelToken.source()`?

Comment: I don't know, it's your code - you mentioned  cancel tokens, I assumed you knew how to use them

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to use a debounce for this, this limits the number of function calls that are made in a certain period of time.

Here's an example using your code: https://codepen.io/rdenton93/pen/MWOoBVK

```
import lodashDebounce from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/lodash.debounce@4.0.8";

document.body.addEventListener('click', async e => {
  const item1 = e.target.closest('.item1');
  const item2 = e.target.closest('.item2');
  const item3 = e.target.closest('.item3');
     
    if(item1) {
      await dummyAsync(); 
      changeContent(1);
    }
    if(item2) {
      await dummyAsync();  
      changeContent(2);
    }
    if(item3) {
      await dummyAsync();
      changeContent(3);
    }
})

function dummyAsync() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(), 2000);
  });
}

const changeContent = lodashDebounce((item) => {
  // Clear previous content
  const wrapper = document.querySelector('.content-wrapper');
  while(wrapper.firstChild) wrapper.removeChild(wrapper.firstChild);
  
  const dummyTable = `<div class="table">This is table number: ${item}</div>`;
  
  // Add table
  wrapper.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', dummyTable);
},1* 1000); // only make one request per second
```

Comment: Hi Robbie, thanks for the suggestion, but I'm not sure that quite gets to the heart of my problem. Rather than preventing another request being made I'd like to replace it, so the 1st set of data never gets displayed :)

Comment: @NickW This will do that as well. If you have a look at the code pen I linked and click button 1, then 2 in quick succession only the content from 2 will show.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks, I hadn't realised it was taking the latest click. There's still a slight issue I've found, in that the codepen *sometimes* does what you expect - I can click 1 then 2 and have it then display the data from 1 and 2 in sequence after the second click. I assume that's because the debounce time is shorter than the max response time?

Comment: @NickW Yes that's right, you can always increase the debounce time if needed, just change this value 1 * 1000 e.g. 2 * 1000 would be 2 seconds

Comment: And an increased debounce time isn't going to make it unresponsive? I'm going to have to look at debounce again, I've clearly not got the right mental model for it. Thanks though, really helpful

Comment: No problem. The debounce is basically waiting to see if the user clicks another tab within a given period of time, in this case, 1 second.  If we increase this it will also increase the amount of time we have to wait for the content to render.

Comment: It was making one change but actually dummyAsync was called for every click

Comment: @NeveenAtik You could always just put the async request in the same function as the changed content. I've updated the codepen to illustrate.

Comment: indeed that would be the best approach I would say @RobbieDenton